# Comparing user input character with a char in Scala

Tags: scala, input, char

I am trying to compare a user's input (in this case X or Y) to a char in Scala.
My code is as follows:

```
    var marker = 0
    while (marker == 0) {
      val ans1 = scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
      println(ans1)
      if (ans1 == 'X') {
        marker = 1
      }
      else if (ans1 == 'Y') {
        marker = 2
      }
      else {
        println("Faulty input. Please retry: X or Y?")
      }
```

However, the result I'm getting is always "Faulty input. Please retry: X or Y?".
So I figure there must be something wrong with my comparisons.

Despite searching, I could not find the problem. I tried changing "" to '' around the chars I'm comparing to (friend's suggestion), but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: The [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/StdIn$.html#readLine():String) is your firend. `readLine` returns a **String** and a **String** is never equals to a **Char**. No matter if the String just has one character and that one is the one you are comparing. - Many options here, one is just to use `readChar` instead. Other is to compare with a **String** `ans1 == "X"`. Another one would be to take just the first character of the **String** like `ans1.head == 'X'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. A string will not equal a character in that if statement.

```
 val ans1 = scala.io.StdIn.readChar()
```